# Assign value to line layer attributes from another layer by lines start / end coordinates

Tags: field-calculator, layers, expression

I have two layers (`Lines` and `Points`). Points are the break points of lines and correspond to start and end of the lines. Lines `start_point_id` and `end_point_id` columns should get `Point_ID` values.

I was thinking to create a field calculator expression by taking Point_id from points layer by lines start and end coordinates. I've managed to get begin and end point ids' as an array, but I need them in separate columns.

```
overlay_intersects('Points', id)
Result: [25, 52]
```

How can I do it using field calculator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the start point use this expression.

```
array_filter(
    overlay_intersects(
        'Points',
        array(id, $geometry)
    ),
    intersects(
        @element[1],
        start_point($geometry)
    )
)[0][0]
```

and for end point

```
array_filter(
    overlay_intersects(
        'Points',
        array(id, $geometry)
    ),
    intersects(
        @element[1],
        end_point($geometry)
    )
)[0][0]
```

Comment: It works, but it takes around 5sec to generate intersecting ids' when creating a new line. Maybe there is another solution?
I used: 

for start point - array_get(overlay_intersects('points', id),0)
for end point - array_get(overlay_intersects('points', id),1)

It works much faster but it generates array of ids' in ascending order and it makes it incorrect.

Comment: @RickyUrban, not sure if it is faster, but try the second expression of the last update. I really don't understand  this expression `array_get(overlay_intersects('points', id),0)`, [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) returns features in arbitrary order if the `filter` parameter isn't specified.

Comment: @RickyUrban, did the last expression worked faster? Or did you find a better expression?

Comment: the last one works perfectly.